# ReplyTo using a shape in an email body

Tags: html, vba, outlook, mailto

I created a shape in an email body that would result in a new email with selected recipients and a subject and body.

Is there anyway I can generate replies to mail with the same subjects and recipients?

Macro or like, there are options in HTML, such as mailto: cc: body: which would sound like replyto.

Comment: What are you asking? How to create a reply to the currently selected email using Outlook Object Model in the button click event handler or how to embed a `mailto` link in the HTML body that will create a reply? The former is possible, the latter is not.

Comment: I meant to ask that i have created a button and added parameters like mailto, cc,bcc,subject,body. This results in opening a new email instead of replying to the email. 

Is there any way for the button to reply to the same email instead of a new one? Using macro?

Comment: How and where did you add the button in Outlook? If it is VBA, you don't need to use the mailto link,.

Comment: using shapes in body

Comment: You cannot run VBA code from an email.

Comment: Oh well, is there any other option/suggestion which would make the button react "replyto" instead of "mailto"? I'm aware "replyto" doesn't exist but wanted an expert opinion. Recommendation or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your post where the button is located - whether it is a message body with a `mailto:` link or a ribbon button on the Outlook UI.

In case of `mailto` protocol there is no way to set up all fields as you reply to the original email.

In case if you customized an Outlook ribbon, your button's event handler you can get the currently selected in the Explorer window or displayed in the active Inspector window item and call the [MailItem.Forward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.forward(method)) method which executes the `Forward` action for an item and returns the resulting copy as a `MailItem` object. For example:

```
Sub RemoveAttachmentBeforeForwarding() 
 Dim myinspector As Outlook.Inspector 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim myattachments As Outlook.Attachments 
 
 Set myinspector = Application.ActiveInspector
 If Not TypeName(myinspector) = "Nothing" Then
   Set myItem = myinspector.CurrentItem.Forward 
   Set myattachments = myItem.Attachments 
   While myattachments.Count > 0 
     myattachments.Remove 1 
   Wend 
   myItem.Display 
   myItem.Recipients.Add "Eugene Astafiev" 
   myItem.Send 
 Else 
   MsgBox "There is no active inspector." 
 End If 
 
End Sub
```

Comment: im not looking for a ribbon, i had added the mailto in body inside a button. As in i just created a rectangle shape and hyperlinked mailto etc.